# prisma.yml could not be found

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma, prisma-binding

I am trying to generate schema for my prisma data model while at the same time using secrets to restrict prisma access. After running `prisma delete` and `prisma deploy`, I run the command `graphql get-schema -p prisma` and get the following error message:

> ✖ prisma/prisma.yml could not be found.

Is there something wrong I am doing in my `.graphqlconfig` or how I am listing my prisma.yml? Thanks.

**.graphqlconfig:**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "prisma": {
      "schemaPath": "generated/prisma.graphql",
      "extensions": {
        "prisma": "prisma/prisma.yml",
        "endpoints": {
          "default": "http://localhost:4466"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**prisma/prisma.yml:**

```
endpoint: http://localhost:4466
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
secret: 'secretFoo'
```

**index.js:**

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import resolvers from './resolvers';
import schema from './generated/prisma.graphql';
import { Prisma } from 'prisma-binding';

const prisma = new Prisma({
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:4466',
  secret: 'secretFoo',
  typeDefs: 'server/generated/prisma.graphql',
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: {
    prisma,
  },
  resolvers,
  typeDefs: schema,
});

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const PORT = 5000;

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`);
  console.log(`Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:${PORT}${server.subscriptionsPath}`);
});

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
  module.hot.dispose(() => server.stop());
}
```

Comment: I ended up using `env-cmd` in my package.json commands and it solved this issue as well, in case any future person runs into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a schema directly from your `prisma.yml` file, by adding the following to the file:

```
generate:
  - generator: graphql-schema
    output: ./generated/prisma.graphql
```

Then you can refer your `.graphqlconfig` to the generated file:

```
projects:
  prisma:
    schemaPath: generated/prisma.graphql
    extensions:
      endpoints:
        dev: http://localhost:4466
```

You would generally restrict access to the management functionality of your endpoint through the Prisma docker-compose file (`managementApiSecret` in `PRISMA_CONFIG`). Then when you run commands like `prisma deploy` you would need to pass the appropriate environment variables through either the `--env-file` flag, or by having a dotenv file in the root of your application's directory (you also need the `dotenv` package installed in `package.json`.

Another way to secure your endpoint is to disable the GraphQL Playground altogether. I believe Apollo Server does this automatically when `NODE_ENV` is set to production, although you can do it explicitly with:

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: {
    prisma,
  },
  resolvers,
  typeDefs: schema,
  playground: false, // <- Here
});
```

I'm sorry, I don't think this directly answered your question, but it may assist either way.